# ¿Cómo pasarle el valor a la función countdown?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función y requiero pasarle un valos desde el HTML, pero no está funcionando.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function countdown(tiempo){
    var timer2 = tiempo;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
  
      var timer = timer2.split(':');
      //by parsing integer, I avoid all extra string processing
      var minutes = parseInt(timer[0], 10);
      var seconds = parseInt(timer[1], 10);
      --seconds;
      minutes = (seconds < 0) ? --minutes : minutes;
      if (minutes < 0) clearInterval(interval);
      seconds = (seconds < 0) ? 59 : seconds;
      seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
      //minutes = (minutes < 10) ?  minutes : minutes;
      $('.countdown').html(minutes + ':' + seconds);
      timer2 = minutes + ':' + seconds;
    }, 1000);
  }
</script>
```

Así la llamo desde el HTML:

```
<div class="countdown" onload="countdown(3)"></div>
```

No me muestra error, pero tampoco envía el valor

Comment: `var timer = timer2.split(':');` debe generar error porque 3 no contiene : debes hacer algo como `var timer = (timer2.indexOf(':')>0) ? timer2.split(':') : [timer2, 0];`

Comment: Si pego tu función en la consola y la  ejecuto se ve el error. a countdown le estás pasando un 3 mientras que haces un split por `:` sobre ese valor.. así que en vez de pasarle un número pásale un string del estilo `"3:0"`

Comment: Gracias a ambos, pero no estoy recibiendo el valor aún pasándolo como string, hago un `console.log(time)` en la primera línea y no lo recibo.

Comment: Quise de decir `console.log(tiempo)` , el cual debería recibir en la siguiente línea `function countdown(tiempo){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El evento [*onload* o *load*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/load) no está disponible en campos de formulario, por lo que debes buscar otra forma de ejecutar la función, por ejemplo, cuando el DOM haya sido cargado.

En vez de enviar parámetro, asigna el valor deseado como texto del contenedor.

```js
// Ejecutar hasta que se cargue el DOM
$(function() {
  // Recorrer todos los elementos con clase countdown
  $('.countdown').each(function() {
      // Identificar elemento actual
      let container = $(this);
      // Separar minutos y segundos
      let timer = $(this).text().split(':');
      // Asignar minutos
      let minutes = parseInt(timer[0]);
      // Asignar segundos (o cero, si no se especificaron)
      let seconds = parseInt(timer[1]) || 0;
      let interval = setInterval(function() {
          --seconds;
          minutes = (seconds < 0) ? --minutes : minutes;
          if (minutes < 0) {
              // Limpiar temporizador y poner valores en cero
              clearInterval(interval);
              minutes = 0;
              seconds = '00';
          } else {
              seconds = (seconds < 0) ? 59 : seconds;
              seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
          }
          // Asignar valor a contenedor
          $(container).text(minutes + ':' + seconds);
      }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countdown">3:00</div>
<div class="countdown">2</div>
<div class="countdown">1:58</div>
```

Comment: Acá funciona pero en mi Web no, voy a revisar con más detenimeinto.

Comment: Listo, subí el jquery al header, lo tenía abajo. Gracias!

Comment: Ahora, cuando hago el llamado varias veces, me mustra todos iguales. Me imagino que debo diferenciar la clase, voy a intentarlo, cualquier cosa hago otra pregunta.

Comment: Listo, ya está para funcionar con varios elementos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ya lo pruebo!

Comment: Gracias, funciona perfecto!

Answer (score 0):

La otra opcion seria poner el onload en la etiqueta body:

```
<body onload="countdown('3:00')">
  <div id="countDown"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Pero siempre es mejor agregar los eventos en el javascript, como ya te respondieron arriba con una funcion auto ejecutable por ejemplo.
O tambien cuentas con el evento DOMContentLoaded

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("El DOM ha cargado completamente");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias, lo que pasa es que debo asignar un tiempo deferente a cada registro